# HP Designjet 130, blank front panel, yellow led flashes, no communication with HP System Maintenance Tool

Tags: printer, network-printer

I replaced the electronics module in my HP Designjet 130 (because the existing one was broken).

I took the electronics module from another working printer I had (HP Designjet 130nr).

The electronics module  was working fine in the HP Designjet 130nr, but the printer hardware was partly worn out/damaged, that's why I wanted to put the electronics module in the HP Designjet 130.

At startup I get the following symptoms:

The display shows a blank lit front panel and the yellow led flashes (cannot turn off the printer or enter the restricted utilities menu "EEPROM clean, factory reset, etc."--nothing moves from there, I can only pull the plug to turn off the printer).

UPDATE:
When the electronics module was in the worn out printer (HP Designjet 130nr) I was able to communicate with the printer via the HP System Maintenance Tool (both USB and network card).--Now, after I installed the electronics module in the present printer I cannot communicate with the printer anymore (no connection or response, HP System Maintenance Tool states that I'm offline).--I don't know what's happening.--All the connections in the the electronics module and also on the printer seem to be connected ok.

Please, will someone knowledgeable point me in the right direction.--Tx.

UPDATE:
The printer is working now.--The problem was caused by the 2-sensor-unit preventing the lids beeing open.

When the sensor is connected nothing moves, when I disconnect the sensor unit, the printer works fine.

Comment: HP printers are rather locked-down, e.g., one cannot even not use an unapproved ink (e.g., https://apnews.com/article/hp-printers-scanner-disabled-low-ink-9d8a0e3b5b49bb408467f7f75735ab0a). It would be surprising if DIY servic e were allowed.

Comment: I note you have 2 different models, 130 and 130nr. That does imply there may be differences in the module. Does it work if you put it back in the original printer?